# подсчет количества значений при group by

Tags: sql, mysqli

есть таблица

```
zapros | result | time | code

1    |  ok    | 14.12 | 200
1    |  err    | 14.12 | 403
1    |  err    | 14.12 | 404
2    |  ok    | 14.12 | 200
3    |  ok    | 14.12 | 200
3    |  ok    | 14.12 | 200
4    |  err    | 14.12 | 404
```

Помогите составить запрос. Нужно сгруппировать по полю zapros, подсчиать для каждого сгруппированного zapros количество ошибок(result = err) и их общее количество. Для каждого сгруппированного zapros нужно еще сгруппировать по code и так же подсчитать какое количество и каких кодов присутствует в таблице. Подсчитать процент успешных запросов по формуле 1-err/all для каждого сгруппированного запрос, и отобрать все все сгруппрованные запросы с коэфф > 0.5
на выходе должно получится

```
zapros | err | all | 200 | 403 | 404 | rate
1      | 2   |  3   | 1  |  1   |  1 | 0.34
2      |  0  |  1   |  1  | 0   |  0 |  1
....
```

Comment: Количество и значения кодов надеюсь фиксированные. потому что динамически создавать столбцы не выйдет

Comment: нет, заранее количество и значения кодов не известно

Comment: Это не возможно. Язык SQL не позволяет динамически менять количество колонок в результате. Каждая колонка должна быть описана в запросе

Comment: Как вариант - писать дикую хранимую процедуру, которая сначала смотрит какие коды вообще встречаются, потом на основании этих данных создает текст sql-запроса и выполняет его

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал использовать средства любого построителя отчётов. Они заточены именно под это.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select zapros,
       sum(result='err') as err,
       count(1) as all,
       sum(code=200) as code200,
       sum(code=403) as code403
  from table
 group by zapros
```

К сожалению только так, все колонки по кодам должны быть описаны в самом запросе. Если нужно динамически - то формировать отдельные строки на каждый код и разворачивать их в горизонталь уже на клиенте.

Comment: Ну или использовать prepared statement, получив список полей из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

Comment: @Akina А чем поможет INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS там же существующие колонки в существующих таблицах

Comment: А, да, пардон... ну тогда ещё проще - обычным запросом получить список кодов, и по нему построить текст запроса. Хотя это не снимает проблемы недетерминированной структуры результата...

Comment: Забыл один момент, внес правку в вопрос о коэфициенте, подскажите как правильно условие вписать?

Comment: @user193361 Ну так и пишите `1 - sum(result='err') / count(1)` и для фильтрации пишите ту же формулу в `having`